# "Fill gasper report from a database" Error in java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, report

I request kindly your help to understand the logic about this Error, i have everytime i try to fill and lunch my jasper report.

This ! is the method that i call to fill my jasper report.

```
public void createReport() {
    try {

        String sql = "select * from "
                + txtNc.getText() + "";
// Connecter is a method which is used to connect to the database "txtNc.getText()" and execute the query "sql" .
        objectcreation.connecter(txtNc.getText(), sql);

        stm = conn.obtenirconnexion().createStatement();
        Rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new
                JRResultSetDataSource(Rs);
        System.out.println("Filling report...");
        JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("/Users/Java_Courses/report.jasper",
        new HashMap(), resultSetDataSource);
        System.out.println("Done!");
        Rs.close();
        stm.close();
    }
    catch (JRException e11)
    {
    e11.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e11)
    {
    e11.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

And this is what i got every time.

```
Filling report...
> oct. 17, 2016 11:06:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/994/0/.cp/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-6.3.1.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/chartThemesBeans.xml]
oct. 17, 2016 11:06:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/994/0/.cp/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-6.3.1.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/chartConstantsBean.xml]
oct. 17, 2016 11:06:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/994/0/.cp/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-6.3.1.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/defaultChartPropertiesBean.xml]
oct. 17, 2016 11:06:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/994/0/.cp/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-6.3.1.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/eyeCandySixtiesChartPropertiesBean.xml]
oct. 17, 2016 11:06:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/994/0/.cp/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-6.3.1.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/aegeanChartPropertiesBean.xml]
Done!
```

Comment: That isn't an error message.  What is youe actual problem here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem, is when i call the method createReport(), nothing happens.Only that message shows up.

Comment: Have you checked the file where standard output is written?

Comment: I have no file for standard outputs, I have only a jrxml file.

Comment: I wanted to pass parameters in the query string of the report but my database is a variable as you could see.Thanks for any valuable help.

Comment: So where is `System.out.println("Filling report...");`  going to be writing stuff?

Comment: @StephenC Do you still have any suggestion for the solution please ! I mentioned that i have only a jrxml file, is there any file missing !

Comment: I have already suggested ... TWICE ... that you find out where the output from the println statements is going.  Have you done that yet?

Comment: Which version of JasperReports are you using?  Have you checked for the ".jrprint" file?  Where did you check?

Comment: I downloaded Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.I am afraid, The lines i posted above are what i read on my console only !

Comment: Sigh ... "Have you checked for the ".jrprint" file? Where did you check?"

Comment: No i didn't check ! I don't know how to check.

Comment: Ermm ... the "ls" command?  Or "find"?

Comment: I apologies for this time long ! i could generate my report but i get this AVERTISSEMENT: Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering.

Comment: Ask a new question